# How do I stop bash from syntax checking sourced files?

Tags: bash, zsh

I have the following code in a file that is sourced by both zsh and bash.

```
if test $SHELLNAME = zsh ; then
    lss() { l -l ${1:-.}/*(s,S,t); }
    laf() { l ${1:-.}/.*(.); }
    lad() { l -d ${1:-.}/.*(/); }
    lsw() { l -ld ${1:-.}/.*(R,W,X.^ND/); }
fi
```

`SHELLNAME` is `zsh` if the shell is zsh and `bash` if the shell is bash.

Each of the above functions contains code that works with zsh, but not bash.

When I source this file, I receive the following errors.

```
bash: <filename>: line 67: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: <filename>: line 67: `     lss() { l -l ${1:-.}/*(s,S,t); }'
```

At the moment, I am using `eval` to bypass bash's syntax checking.

```
if test $SHELLNAME = zsh ; then
    # Using eval makes sure bash can't try to syntax-check these functions.
    eval 'lss() { l -l ${1:-.}/*(s,S,t); }'
    eval 'laf() { l ${1:-.}/.*(.); }'
    eval 'lad() { l -d ${1:-.}/.*(/); }'
    eval 'lsw() { l -ld ${1:-.}/.*(R,W,X.^ND/); }'
fi
```

Is there a better solution to this problem? (perhaps one that doesn't use `eval`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You only need one eval.

```
[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] &&
  eval '
    lss() l -l ${1:-.}/*(s,S,t)
    laf() l ${1:-.}/.*(.)
    lad() l -d ${1:-.}/.*(/)
    lsw() l -ld ${1:-.}/.*(R,W,X.^ND/)
  '
```

(note that `zsh` contrary to `bash` does support the Bourne function syntax)

Or:

```
[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && . /dev/fd/3 3<< '# End of zsh specific section'
  lss() l -l ${1:-.}/*(s,S,t)
  laf() l ${1:-.}/.*(.)
  lad() l -d ${1:-.}/.*(/)
  lsw() l -ld ${1:-.}/.*(R,W,X.^ND/)
# End of zsh specific section
```

But I'd tend to agree with `slm` that having the `zsh` specific syntax in a separate file only sourced by `zsh` would make sense.

Comment: Thanks for putting into code what I could only think of in words 8-).

Answer (score 16):

Rather than try and get Bash to not syntax check, why not have your script that's doing the sourcing of this only source it when it's being called by the correct shell.

Comment: The file is sourced by both bash and zsh. I'm thinking about splitting the zsh-specific parts into their own file though.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I would do. It's clearer to maintain and support for yourself down the road and for anyone else that comes into the code in the future. In code I always try for explicit rather than clever.